When I add my reference chapter it comes out as Chapter 1: *. How should I fix it?
I use this code and it makes it look like the attached image. Whereas, I want it to say just "References" Left aligned as the title and then the list of references below. Please help!
For context I am writing my Thesis so I have it set in book format.
My Main File:
\documentclass{bcwthesis}
\RequirePackage{tocloft} % For creating custom lists

%% DOCUMENT ===================================================================
%
\begin{document}

\frontmatterstyle

\tableofcontentssection
\listoffiguressection
\listoftablessection
\listofequationssection

% Add Abbreviations and Definitions
\abbreviationsection

% Add Nomenclature
\nomenclaturesection



\startmainmatter
\setcounter{chapter}{1} % Set chapter counter to 0 so first chapter is numbered 1
% Main matter starts here...
\include{Chapters/introduction}


% Include the bibliography in IEEE style
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}  % Use IEEE style for bibliography
\bibliography{references}  % Your .bib file


\end{document}

And this is my class file:
    %% Opening bits and bobs
    \NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
    \ProvidesClass{bcwthesis}[2024/10/07 v1.4 BCW thesis class]
    
    %% Load base class and set font size to 12pt
    \def\baseclass{book}
    \LoadClass[12pt,openany]{\baseclass} % Disable forced blank pages before new chapters
    
    % Required packages
    \RequirePackage{xkeyval} % Key-value options
    \RequirePackage{graphicx} % Graphics inclusion
    \RequirePackage{tocbibind} % Automatically includes TOC, LOF, LOT in TOC
    \RequirePackage{nomencl} % Nomenclature support
    \RequirePackage{amsmath} % Math support
    \RequirePackage{fancyhdr} % Header/Footer customization
    \RequirePackage{tocloft} % Custom lists (e.g., List of Equations)
    \RequirePackage{geometry} % Page layout
    
    
    %% Page Layout
    \PassOptionsToPackage{%
      top=3cm,
      bottom=3cm,
      inner=3cm,
      outer=2cm,
      head=15pt
    }{geometry}
    
    %% Apply Double Line Spacing by Default
    \linespread{1.6} % This applies 1.6x (double) line spacing
    
    
    
    %% FRONT MATTER STYLES: Roman numeral page numbers
    \newcommand{\frontmatterstyle}{
      \pagestyle{fancy}
      \fancyhf{} % Clear headers and footers
      \fancyfoot[C]{\thepage} % Center the page number in the footer
      \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % No header line
      \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt} % No footer line
      \pagenumbering{Roman} % Capitalized Roman numerals
      \setcounter{page}{0} % Start front matter at "I"
    }
    
    
    
   emphasized text
    %% TOC, LOF, LOT Setup (Centered Titles with Content)
    \newcommand{\tableofcontentssection}{%
        % Temporarily suppress the TOC depth to prevent "Contents" from being listed
        \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{-1}} 
        \begin{center}
            \tableofcontents
        \end{center}
        % Restore the TOC depth so that following sections appear normally in the TOC
        \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}} % Adjust depth to your needs
    }
    
    \newcommand{\listoffiguressection}{%
        \newpage
        \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Figures}
        \begin{center}
            \listoffigures
        \end{center}
    }
    
    \newcommand{\listoftablessection}{%
        \newpage
        \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Tables}
        \begin{center}
            \listoftables
        \end{center}
    }
    
    %% CUSTOM LIST OF EQUATIONS
    % Define a list of equations using `tocloft`
    \newlistof{myequations}{equ}{List of Equations}
    \newcommand{\addequation}[1]{%
        \refstepcounter{equation}%
        \addcontentsline{equ}{myequations}{\protect\numberline{\theequation}#1}%
    }
    
    \newcommand{\listofequationssection}{%
        \newpage
        \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Equations}
        \begin{center}
            \listofmyequations
        \end{center}
    }
    
    \newcommand{\abbreviationsection}{%
        \chapter*{\centering \bfseries Abbreviations and Definitions}
        \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abbreviations and Definitions}
        \begin{flushleft}
        \begin{description}
            % Entries will be added in the main document
        \end{description}
        \end{flushleft}
        %\clearpage
    }
    
    %% Nomenclature & Abbreviations
    \newcommand{\nomenclaturesection}{%
        \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Nomenclature} % Add Nomenclature to TOC
        \printnomenclature
        \newpage % Do not include \clearpage or \newpage unless necessary
    }
    
    
    %% NOMENCLATURE SUPPORT
    \makenomenclature
    
    %% MAIN MATTER: Switch to Arabic page numbers and reset chapter counter
    \newcommand{\startmainmatter}{
        %\cleardoublepage
        \pagenumbering{arabic} % Switch to Arabic numerals
        \setcounter{page}{1} % Start at page 1 for the main matter
        \setcounter{chapter}{0} % Reset chapter counter so first chapter starts at 1
        %% Now redefine the \chapter command for the main matter
        \renewcommand{\chapter}[1]{%
          \if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi % Ensures new chapters start on a right-hand page
          \thispagestyle{plain} % Ensures chapter starts with a plain page style (no headers)
          \global\@topnum\z@ % Prevent floats at the top of the page
          \vspace*{50pt} % Space before the title
          \begin{center} % Center the title and number
            {\normalfont\Huge\bfseries Chapter \thechapter: ##1}% Combine chapter number and title on one line
            \par\nobreak\vspace{40pt} % Space after the title
          \end{center}%
          \@afterheading
        }
    }
    
    
    %% Adjust sub-headings to be left justified
    \renewcommand{\section}{\@startsection{section}{1}{\z@}{-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}{2.3ex \@plus.2ex}{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}} % Left justified sections
    \renewcommand{\subsection}{%
        \@startsection{subsection}{2}{\z@}%
        {-3.25ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}% Before the subsection title
        {2.3ex \@plus .2ex}% After the subsection title
        {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}% Style of subsection title
    }

Chapter 1 File contents:
\chapter{Introduction}
Your introduction text here. 



You've not shown us anything that will create "Chapter 1: *".  Could you post a complete example (but with only the minimal amount of code necessary)?

@Teepeemm added more information. Thanks for responding :-)

Let's start working through https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228 (it's often easiest to do this in a separate project).  We don't have Chapters/introduction.tex, so we can't use your \include.  I think that's what's creating your "Chapter 1: *" (possibly with a \chapter{*} command that should be \chapter*{Introduction}).  Do you still have the problem if you use the document class book instead of bcwthesis?

@Teepeemm Ah so when I transfer to Book class it works fine but then everything before is destroyed

You've still not made it easy, but \startmainmatter is redefining \chapter badly.  Can you stop using that command?  It would be better to use secsty to apply the styling you want to the chapter and section headings.

to elaborate on what @Teepeemm said, the class you're using redefines \chapter so that it no longer supports the optional star. So, once you start the main matter, you cannot create unnumbered chapters (without resorting to low level hacks). if this class is required by your institution, it probably means you're not allowed to use unnumbered chapters here. otherwise, the best solution would be to use a different class.

As mentioned, the class file is (badly) redefining \chapter, so that it breaks the bibliography.  With the titlesec package, you should change the \startmainmatter command to
\newcommand{\startmainmatter}{
    \mainmatter
    \@openrighttrue
    \titleformat{\chapter}[block]{\centering\Huge\bfseries}{Chapter \thechapter:}{.5em}{}
}

You appear to be using natbib commands for your bibliography (the one referencing style you didn't use as a tag), so you need
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\renewcommand\bibname{References}
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}  % Use IEEE style for bibliography

and then just before you include the \bibliography, call
\titleformat{\chapter}{\Huge\bfseries}{Chapter \thechapter:}{.5em}{}

(Also, don't do \linespread{1.6}.  Instead, \usepackage{setspace} \doublespacing.)
